# How to compute nfft

Tags: python, fft, nfft

I'm trying to understand how to use the `nfft` method of [Jake Vanderplas' `nfft` module](https://github.com/jakevdp/nfft#basic-usage).  The example unfortunately isn't very illustrative as I try to parametrize everything based on just an input list of samples (`[(time0, signal0), (time1, signal1), ...]`):

```
import numpy as np
from nfft import nfft

# define evaluation points
x = -0.5 + np.random.rand(1000)

# define Fourier coefficients
N = 10000
k = - N // 2 + np.arange(N)
f_k = np.random.randn(N)

# non-equispaced fast Fourier transform
f = nfft(x, f_k)
```

I'm trying to compute f_k in an example where the samples are about 10 ms apart with 1 or 2 ms jitter in that interval.

The implementation documentation:

```
def nfft(x, f_hat, sigma=3, tol=1E-8, m=None, kernel='gaussian',
         use_fft=True, truncated=True):
    """Compute the non-equispaced fast Fourier transform

    f_j = \sum_{-N/2 \le k < N/2} \hat{f}_k \exp(-2 \pi i k x_j)

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : array_like, shape=(M,)
        The locations of the data points. Each value in x should lie
        in the range [-1/2, 1/2).
    f_hat : array_like, shape=(N,)
        The amplitudes at each wave number k = range(-N/2, N/2).
```

Where I'm stuck:

```
import numpy as np
from nfft import nfft

def compute_nfft(sample_instants, sample_values):
    """
    :param sample_instants: `numpy.ndarray` of sample times in milliseconds
    :param sample_values: `numpy.ndarray` of samples values
    :return: Horizontal and vertical plot components as `numpy.ndarray`s
    """
    N = len(sample_instants)
    T = sample_instants[-1] - sample_instants[0]
    x = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0 / (2.0 * T), N // 2)
    y = 2.0 / N * np.abs(y[0:N // 2])
    y = nfft(x, y)
    return (x, y)
```

Answer (score 4):

The example defines a variable `f_k` which is passed as `nfft`'s `f_hat` argument.
According to the definition

> ```
> f_j = \sum_{-N/2 \le k < N/2} \hat{f}_k \exp(-2 \pi i k x_j)
> ```

given, `f_hat` represents the time-domain signal at the specified sampling instants. In your case this simply corresponds to `sample_values`.

The other argument `x` of `nfft` are the actual time instants of those samples. You'd need to also provide those separately:

```
def compute_nfft(sample_instants, sample_values):
    N = len(sample_instants)
    T = sample_instants[-1] - sample_instants[0]
    x = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0 / (2.0 * T), N // 2)
    y = nfft(sample_instants, sample_values)
    y = 2.0 / N * np.abs(y[0:N // 2])
    return (x, y)
```

Comment: Can I interest you in a [bounty for a 2D FFT question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61718126/176769)?

Comment: I don't understand how this can be correct. The documentation of nfft(x, f_k) says `x : array_like, shape=(M,) The locations of the data points. Each value in x should lie in the range [-1/2, 1/2)`. You're invoking nfft with `sample_instants` as x, which are the times in milliseconds, so not in this range.